# Swift 4 Codable , CodingKey only for decode

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, codable

Is it possible that  `CodingKey` can be used for only `JSONEncoder` and for `JSONDecoder` use default member names  ?

Example I have following structure

```
var str = """
{
"name": "Endeavor",
"abv": 8.9,
"brewery": "Saint Arnold",
"style": "ipa"
}

"""

enum BeerStyle:String,Codable {
    case ipa
    case stout
    case kolsch
}

struct Beer : Codable {
    let name : String
    let brewery : String
    let style : BeerStyle
    let abv : Float

    // THIS SHOULD BE USED ONLY FOR JSONEncoder ? 
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case name
        case abv = "alcohol_by_volume"
        case brewery = "brewery_name"
        case style
    }
}

let jsonData = str.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder() // how to to make it not to use Coding key
let beer = try! decoder.decode(Beer.self, from: jsonData)
```

will not work fine since   `enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey` is there

Any one can suggest me a idea or link ?

Comment: (It's ["kölsch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kölsch_(beer)), not "kolsch"  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add two enums one for encoding and one for decoding, e.g. `EncodingKeys` and `DecodingKeys`
2. Write custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` implementations like this.

.

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: EncodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    // ...
}
```

and

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DecodingKeys.self)
    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    // ...
}
```

**Update** 
I tried it with just one implementation of `encode(...)`. You just need to rename the Enum to `EncodingKeys.self` (or something else). Then implement the encode-function like described above. For decoding the CodingKeys and init-function are being synthesized.

Comment: Thanks for answer !!, `encode` function will used to `JSONDecoder` or `JSONEncoder` ?

Comment: The `encode` function implements the custom encoding with the `JSONEncoder` as the name suggests :)

Comment: Your answer is somehow correct, But what i ask is `CodingKey` enum can be used for `JSONEncoder` only for Decoder i don't want extra enum

Comment: Yeah as I wrote in my update of the answer: Rename your enum to `EncodingKeys`. So you can use this for `JSONEncoder` with a custom implementation of `func encode(to encoder: Encoder)...` like in my code snipped above.
After renaming there is no `CodingKeys` enum anymore, so the compiler generates one in the background which will be used for `JSONDecoder`. And those coding keys will be de default ones, therefore will be the same like your property names.

Comment: If I use two enums one for encoder and one for decoder then it works fine.  as . you said for json decoder it will create enum in background that is not working  !! Please add example in code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fl034/3ccf395e9f70776b6e309db30a0a0a6e
Look at this gist :-).